# Move installation to an other HD

Tags: installation, hard-drive, files

By mistake I have installed my ubuntu 11 on a wrong drive. What's the damage I face? A new installation?  Is there any tweak for that?

This is a 80GB western digital that needs to be shifted to 350GB western digital. I have configured the machine to be my dev machine, after 2 days of configuration I discovered the mess.  I want to move it completely, like an "image", any chance for that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give us some additional information on your hardware/setup? Do you have data that need rescue?

Comment: @enzotib @fatnjazzy is the 350 Gb disc formatted (fat? ntfs? ext3? ext4?) and empty?

Comment: @Rinzwind: obviously I don't know, I edited my answer saying I suppose so.

Comment: @enzotib that's why I included you ;) That cp of yours could go very wrong it it mixes with an existing install.

Comment: @Rinzwind: yeah, I suppose the user is not a complete noob, but maybe I'm wrong :) new edit of my answer required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Copy data

start wih a livecd/liveusb, mount the old and the new partition, then copy everything with

```
sudo cp -ax /media/old/. /media/new
```

I'm supposing the new partition is already formatted in ext4 or similar, and completely empty.

- modify `fstab`

modify the file `/media/new/etc/fstab` to point to the new UUID (obtained with `sudo blkid`);

- update grub

remove the old disk and (through a chroot), update and reinstall grub to the new disk MBR, following the usual procedures.